# Update boolean and create new records simultaneously - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I need to update a Boolean and also create new records at the same time.
I have a controller called Bank, and Bank has 3 attributes, namely `account:string`, `amount:decimal` and `withdrawn:Boolean`, a customer can invest an amount for a specific number of days, after those days are reached they can then withdraw the amount with interest. I need that when the customer clicks withdraw the `withdrawn` Boolean is updated to `true`, and the amount+interest for example `amount+10%` is created and saved, the amount+10% result will also have a Boolean/flag paid which the “bank teller” can change to `paid:, true` after the cash payment is done.

How can I achieve the above, should I create a new controller and model for the Withdrawal, and how would that code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create a new controller. Just create a `withdraw` method in your controller. Not sure exactly what you mean with the amount+interest but I guess you're talking about another column in your database.  Just add something like `amount_with_interest` as an attribute in the database. Also, add another column for `paid`, as a boolean.

```
def withdraw
the_bank = Bank.find(params[:id]) #or something similar to get the account one way or another 
the_bank.withdrawn = true 
the_bank.amount_with_interest = the_bank.amount * 1.1
the_bank.save
end
```

The teller can then press some other button somewhere after the payment has been sent that simply changes `the_bank.paid` to true

Comment: as far as Rails methods and syntax go, do I not need to do `the_bank.update(:withdrawn, true)`, and `the_bank.create` to save the amount_with_interest?

Comment: Not necessarily.  It is conventional to update attributes of a Model through the edit page, then posting to the update route in your controller, but there is nothing special about those 2 actions.  What I'm doing int he above example is essentially creating a new update action that only changes the attributes you want to change.  As far as using the_bank.update(:withdrawn, true), this is perfectly valid syntax, but the the_bank.create will create a new instance of the Bank model.  I've updated my answer to include the line the_bank.save, which is all you need to make these changes take effect.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is well explained and precise.